# Highcharts: hide lines for categories

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this config for `xAxis`:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  crosshair: true,
  showFirstLabel: true,
  showLastLabel: true,
  categories: props.currentPeriodDays,
  labels: {
    step: 20
  }
}
```

How I can hide these lines?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding `gridLineWidth: 0` or `tickWidth: 0`?

So the code would look something like:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  crosshair: true,
  showFirstLabel: true,
  showLastLabel: true,
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  tickWidth: 0,
  categories: props.currentPeriodDays,
  labels: {
    step: 20
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It's `0` by default, https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.gridLineWidth and It didn't help

Comment: `tickLength: 0` might be the issue then. That defaults to 2. Beyond that, I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer does answer the question that was asked, let me offer a different approach for reference.

You are plotting time-series data, which Highcharts handles extremely well when using an axis type of `datetime`, rather than trying to shoehorn dates into a `category` axis.

Without using `categories`, the chart will automatically produce a logical set of ticks/gridlines/axis labels, rather than creating them for each data point.

If the results don't completely meet your requirements, you can easily correct them by setting an appropriate `tickInterval`.

If you don't want any `tickmarks` at all, you can still hide them by setting the `tickWidth` or the `tickLength` to 0, but by sending the data as `datetime` data, and using a `datetime` axis, you may eliminate the need to, as there won't be so many created (and you will have a cleaner, more logical chart object as well).

References:

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval
- https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes

Demos:

- https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series
  *